# How to manually specify the current active page with wp_nav_menu()

Tags: menus

Is there a way of manually specifying which page is currently "active" when using `wp_nav_menu()`?

I have a "Products" page, and on that page I have links to various (dynamic) custom taxonomies. When I click on one of these taxonomies, I stay on the "Products" page but `wp_nav_menu()` loses reference to that fact that I'm still on the "Products" page. Is there a way I can fix this?

Thanks!

Jon

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just want to add the `current_page_item` class to one menu item, you could hook up to the `nav_menu_css_class` filter, and add that class if needed. It is called [when the menu is printed](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L76).

If you want access to the whole menu and add classes, hook in to the `wp_get_nav_menu_items` filter, where you get the whole `$items` array. You can edit the `classes` properties of individual items.

Answer (score 2):

**@Jon**
As long as you are using `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>` WordPress will assign the class `current_page_item` to your menu along with `current_page_parent` if your using drop down menus.

Comment: Hi Chris,

Thanks for the reply.

I am using the <body <?php body_class(); ?>> tag but the problem is that as far as the wp_nav_menu() is concerned the taxonomies im clicking on are unrelated to it! 

So, i need to say to wp_nav_menu() - if the page is X then show "Products" as the current_page_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Jan mentioned nav_menu_css_class filter, so I looked it up and this example was helpful to me 
Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_css_class

```
function my_special_nav_class( $classes, $item ) {
    if ( is_single() && $item->title == 'Blog' ) {
        $classes[] = 'special-class';
    }
    return $classes;
}    
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'my_special_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```