# Remove current-menu-item for a specific link

Tags: menus

bbPress uses a custom post type called forums.  When I click on forums, both forums and the Blog menu items are highlighted as a current-menu-item.

Is there a way to remove the current-menu-item from Blog when the post-type = forum?

Comment: Check this answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/how-to-manually-specify-the-current-active-page-with-wp-nav-menu/1250#1250

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to format my CSS rules accordingly. If you're using `body_class()` you can always target `single-posttype` so as a quick example

```
.single-posttype .current-menu-item { display: none; }
```

Will hide the current menu item when you're on a specific post type. If this makes sense hehe. Another way would be creating your own navigation menu Walker and running some additional checks inside.

Answer (score 0):

i would use jquery

```
$('#menu-item-xxx').removeClass('current-menu-item');
```